# How to track salesforce report exports

Tags: reporting, data-export

I would like to be able to track exports of reports including the filters of the reports. Do you know of any way that this is possible outside of manual recording?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have event monitoring enabled, you can use its REST API to track that.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/using_resources_event_log_files.htm?search_text=Report